# ElasticSearch support for highlighting in nested query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am new to this concept of searching using elasticsearch. Had a query related to highlighting in elastic.

Below is the query what I am executing on elastic search.  But it throws me error saying "[nested] query does not support [highlight]".

Can anyone show me a path where I can achieve highlighting feature of elasticsearch.

```
  GET 
{
   "query":{
    "nested": {
         "path": "doc.nested_assignments",
         "query": {
            "query_string": {
               "query": "doc.nested_assignments.searchfield:SearchText"
            }
         },         

    "highlight": {
        "fields": { 
            "doc.nested_assignments.searchfield":{}
        }
    }
    }
   }
}
```

Thanks, 
-Jack